# Excel formula find the shortest string / two digits in a cell

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, substring, string-length

in cell A1, I have strings in this format:
`xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx 00 xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx`

As you can see one (and only one) of these strings is a 2-digit string (e.g. `02`). Also this is the shortest string in the cell. Before the `00` part there can be 2-5 words.

I need to find these two digits / shortest string in the cell and write it in cell A2.

Comment: Use find() to get the position of all the spaces.

Comment: Hi mike, before the 00 string there can be 2-5 words, I'll edit the original post with this info, meaning the shortest word is not after the third space

Comment: I did not say 3rd space, I said **all**, so once you have that info you can get all the lengths...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will extract two digits from the position of the first instance:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),2)
```

[image]

Put it inside `VALUE()` if you need the actual number:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe, in `B1` enter formula :

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(" ?? ",A1)+1,2)
```

[image]

Comment: I think that fits all criteria from the OP quite nicely! +

Comment: A very clever use of wildcards!

Comment: guys I'm bringing my question from 4 months ago, =MID(A1,SEARCH(" ?? ",A1)+1,2) worked perfectly, but now sometimes I have other 2 digits strings before the string I want. To be more clear I need: The first two digits string in a cell but both digits have to be numbers: example "02" is good, "as" is not good, any help will be much appreciated!